# How to do parallel Ajax request with jQuery for Posting and Commenting Mechanism

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.net MVC, I am trying to make post and comment mechanism,I can comment and post and I add them to database in different tables, I can also take comment from database to Index.cshtml page with Ajax request via jQuery. I have try to take post and post's comment simultaneously, I have created **Paralel()** function which is given below but I do not have any idea how to take comment and post simultaneously in that function. Could you help me? Thanks.

**getPosts():**

```
function getPosts() {
        var toSend = new Object();
        if (timestamOfLastPost == null) {
            toSend.timestampFrom = 4294967295;//MAX_INT
        }
        else {
            toSend.timestampFrom = timestamOfLastPost;
        }
        toSend.numberOfPosts = 2;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetPosts',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(toSend),
            dataType: "json",
            async:true,
            success:function (data) {
                $.each(data.postList, function (i, post) {
                    postsHtml += getMessageHtml(post.title, post.message, post.ID, "", "");
                     });
                $("#posts").html(postsHtml);
                timestamOfLastPost = data.timestamp;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                alert('Error message.');
            }
        });
    }
```

**getComment():**

```
 function getComment()
    {
        if (timestamOfLastComment == null) {
            //toSend.timestampFrom = Date.now() / 1000 | 0;
            toSend.timestampFrom = 4294967295;//MAX_INT
        }
        else {
            toSend.timestampFrom = timestamOfLastPost;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/getComment',
            type: 'POST',
            async:true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(toSend),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
   $.each(data.comment, function (i) {
   comment += getComment(comment.message,comment.author_Id,comment.Post_ID)              
                });
          }

            });
    }
```

**Paralel:**

```
function Paralel()
        {
            $.when($.ajax("/Home/GetPosts"), $.ajax("/Home/Comment")).done(function(a1, a2)
            {
               ///To take post and comment

            });

        }
```

**getCommentHtml():**

```
function getCommentHtml(message, author_Id, Post_ID)
    {
        var result = '';
        result += "<label>";
        result += message;
        result += "</label>";
    }
```

**getMessageHtml():**

```
function getMessageHtml(title, message,ID,comment_ID,comment_message) {
var result = '';
            result += "<div class=\"row col-md-8\">";
            result += "<div class=\"row\">";
            result += "<h2>" + title + "</h2>";
            result += "</div>\n";
            result += "<div class=\"row\">";
            result += message;
            result += "</div>\n";
            result += "<hr width='%100'>";
            result += "<div style='margin-left:100px' class=\"row\">";
            result += "<hr width='%100'>";
            result += "<form action='#' method='post'>";
            result += "\n<textarea id='comment";
            result += ID
            result += "'></textarea>\n";
            result += "\n<input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' OnClick='doComment("

            result += ")' value='Comment' />";
            result += "</div>\n";
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your *Paralel* fucntion to this will work:

```
function Paralel() {
   getPosts();
   getComment()
}
```

Your code with run in "parallel" because $.ajax is asynchronous.

In your example, your are trying to use promises to do something *$.when* the promises (getPosts, getComment) where resolved.
The $.ajax are prepared to be promised but your functions (getPosts, getComment) not. You have to use jQuery promises (https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/)